# Should unused bytes go on the left or right

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, byte, endianness

Let's say I have a number `12` and it should represent 4 bytes. Would the correct way to format it be:

```
format_in_bytes(value=12, num_bytes=4)
b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00'
```

or:

```
format_in_bytes(value=12, num_bytes=4)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0c'
```

Comment: did you mean to write `\xc0`? 12 in hex is `0c` not `c0`. As for the answer to your question, I feel like the answer is "either, but it should be consistent throughout your application". How do you need to use this output elsewhere?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy yes, that's correct thanks for pointing that out. Incidentally, is there an easy way to format the bytes so it "pads it" to a full byte? That is, `0x0c` instead of `'0xc'`

Comment: `bytes(value // (256 ** i) % 256 for i in range(num_bytes))` will do it for you in little-endian - the built-in `bytes()` will produce a value of your desired format given an iterable of integers less than 256. To do big-endian, instead use either `reversed(range(num_bytes))` or `range(num_bytes, -1, -1)`.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy thanks. What's more common for networking, little or big endian?